# Very slow debugging

Tags: qt, gdb

I've cross compiled Qt and created SD card image and mounted using `losetup`. Compiation is much faster now compared to direct `sshfs` mount. Application runs OK. Now, I want to debug which is dead slow and it appears like it is copying the files back to the dev machine for debugging. I see this suggestion:

`File transfers from remote targets can be slow. Use "set sysroot" to access files locally instead.`

I'm using `gdb-multiarch` and have got `gdbserver` (on target board).

I'm kind of lost here. Where to set this option? I've supplied `--sysroot` argument to the binary but no use. Any help is really appreciated.

Update: using Qt Creator for the development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sysroot` is a gdb setting.  You can set it in gdb with the `set sysroot` command.  For example:

```
(gdb) help set sysroot 
Set an alternate system root.
The system root is used to load absolute shared library symbol files.
For other (relative) files, you can add directories using
`set solib-search-path'.
```

This setting controls how gdb tries to find various files it needs, and in particular the executable and shared libraries that you are debugging.

Recent versions of gdb default `sysroot` to `target:`, which means "fetch the files from the target".  If you're debugging locally, this is just local filesystem access; but if you are debugging remotely and have a slow connection, this can be a bit painful.  In order to make this faster, the idea is to keep a local copy of all the files you'll need, and then use `set sysroot` to point gdb at this local copy.

The main issue with this approach is that if your local copy is out of sync with the remote, you can end up confusing gdb and getting nonsense results.  I am not certain but maybe enabling build-ids alleviates this problem somewhat (certainly in theory gdb can detect build-id mismatches and warn, I just don't recall whether it actually does).

Comment: @ramtheconqueror So? Qt Creator is an IDE, not a debugger. It uses gdb to debug your code on the target. You can issue debugger commands from within Qt Creator's debugger log/command pane. Show it by going to the following menu item: `Window->Views->Debugger Log`. There you can change the sysroot setting.

Answer (score 1):

As Tom Tromey suggested adding `set sysroot {my sysroot local path}` as a starting command in the debugger has worked for me.

[image: sysroot setup]